# Displaying data from local storage

Tags: angular

I've made a mock car-dealership app which displays a list of cars pulled from a .json file.

If the local storage item 'cars' is empty, the app shows the list of cars from the .json file, if the item is full then the page should display cars from local storage.

[image: car list pulled from .json]

How can I display local storage data instead of data from .json file?

**car-list.component.ts**

```
errorMessage: string = '';
sub!: Subscription;

private _listFilter: string = '';

get listFilter(): string {
   return this._listFilter;
}
set listFilter(value: string) {
   this._listFilter = value;
   this.filteredCars = this.performFilter(value);
}

filteredCars: ICar[] = [];
cars: ICar[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.carService.getItem('cars')) {
      console.log('%ccar-list.component.ts line:52 yes', 'color: #007acc;');

      // this.sub = this.carService.getCarsLocal().subscribe({
      //   next: (cars) => {
      //     (this.cars = cars), (this.filteredCars = this.cars);
      //   },
      //   error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
      // });
    } else {
      this.sub = this.carService.getCars().subscribe({
        next: (cars) => {
          (this.cars = cars), (this.filteredCars = this.cars);
          this.carService.setItem('cars', this.cars);
        },
        error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
      });
    }
  }

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**car.service.ts**

```
 private carUrl = '/api/cars/cars.json';
  private readonly cars$ = this.http
    .get<ICar[]>(this.carUrl)
    .pipe(shareReplay(1), catchError(this.handleError));

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  storedData: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      storageKey: '',
      storageData: '',
    });
  }

  getCars(): Observable<ICar[]> {
    return this.cars$;
  }

  getCarById(id: number): Observable<ICar | undefined> {
    const savedCar: any = localStorage.getItem('id');
    if (savedCar) {
      return savedCar;
    } else {
      return this.cars$.pipe(
        map((cars) => cars.find((car) => car.carId === id))
      );
    }
  }

  public getCarsLocal() {
    let cars: any = this.getItem('cars');
    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {}
  }

  public updateItem(key: string, data: any) {
    let cars: any = this.getItem('cars');
    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      if (cars[i].carId === key) {
        cars[i] = data;
      }
    }

    this.setItem('cars', cars);
  }

  public setItem(key: string, data: any): void {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  public getItem(key: string): string {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  }

  public removeItem(key): void {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  public clear() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  onSetData() {
    this.setItem(
      this.formGroup.get('storageKey').value,
      this.formGroup.get('storageData').value
    );
  }

  onGetData() {
    this.storedData = this.getItem(this.formGroup.get('storageKey').value);
  }

  onRemoveData() {
    this.removeItem(this.formGroup.get('storageKey').value);
  }

  onClearData() {
    this.clear();
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = `An error occurred:  ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(() => errorMessage);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (this.carService.getItem('cars')) {
  console.log('%ccar-list.component.ts line:52 yes', 'color: #007acc;');

  // this.sub = this.carService.getCarsLocal().subscribe({
  //   next: (cars) => {
  //     (this.cars = cars), (this.filteredCars = this.cars);
  //   },
  //   error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
  // });
} else {
  this.sub = this.carService.getCars().subscribe({
    next: (cars) => {
      (this.cars = cars), (this.filteredCars = this.cars);
      this.carService.setItem('cars', this.cars);
    },
    error: (err) => (this.errorMessage = err),
  });
}
```

In this if-else block, I think you need to check in `localStorage`, but you are using `this.carService`.

Replacing it with `localStorage.getItem('cars')` should do the task.

Comment: Inside carService is a method called getItem which returns JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) which is the same

Comment: Hello @k0uva, Can you please provide a detailed code for carService?